# Error index of start GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY postgresql

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

```
CREATE TABLE student (
    id int8 NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (
    START 1),
   name varchar(255)
);
```

```
insert into student(name) values('me1');
insert into student(name) values('me2');
insert into student(name) values('me3');
insert into student(name) values('me4');
```

So now in my database existing 4 records.

Alter that I use hibernate insert new record but It show error duplicate key `id`
So I need try insert 4 time to reach last index of records after reached last records it will work fine.

**Question**: 
how to set start in `IDENTITY` to auto ?

Thank you.

Comment: You should tell your obfuscation layer, not to send an ID to the database.

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name can you detail it, sorry I don't clear.

Comment: When I insert my id is null